# Get available Dependencies using pom.xml in Command line, like eclipse dependency search in m2eclipse plugin

Tags: maven

Maven eclipse plugin can search available dependencies from the default repositories and any additional repositories configured, given that I know the partial group Id or partial artifact Id. This is really useful in finding the available dependencies. Is there a similar mechanism available using maven in command line.

Example: suppose I know only **"mybatis"**, and I intend to find the proper *group id, artifact id,* and *version* and whether *type* **jar** is available or not. I can easily do this using eclipse search dependency. But without eclipse do I really need to use the browser and go to repo2.maven.org (and now I find that directory browsing of this has been disabled).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can search the sonatype repository, which covers a lot of ground. (I'm not sure how many other repo's are mirrored though this. I guess that's a separate question.)

Second, nexus itself has an API that you can use to script queries against the repository. For example, you can use [Ruby or Groovy](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2008/11/searching-with-the-sonatype-nexus-rest-api-groovy/) and do something like (assuming groovy is installed; I'm on linux):

```
$ cat foo.groovy
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

def xml = args.length < 2 ? 
            "http://repository.sonatype.org/service/local/data_index?q=" + args[0] : 
            "http://repository.sonatype.org/service/local/data_index?g=${args[0]}&a=${args[1]}&v=${args[2]}"

println "Searching: " + xml

def root = new XmlParser().parseText( xml.toURL().text )
root.data.artifact.each {
  println "${it.groupId.text()}:${it.artifactId.text()}:${it.version.text()}"
}
```

Then,

```
$ ./foo.groovy  org.mybatis mybatis  3.0.4
Searching: http://repository.sonatype.org/service/local/data_index?g=org.mybatis&a=mybatis&v=3.0.4
org.mybatis:mybatis:3.0.4
org.mybatis:mybatis:3.0.4
org.mybatis:mybatis:3.0.4
```

Or, closer your question (output truncated),

```
$ ./foo.groovy  mybatis
Searching: http://repository.sonatype.org/service/local/data_index?q=mybatis
org.mybatis:mybatis:3.0.1
org.mybatis:mybatis:3.0.1
...
org.mybatis.caches:mybatis-caches-parent:1.0.0-RC1
org.mybatis.caches:mybatis-ehcache:1.0.0-RC1
org.mybatis.caches:mybatis-ehcache:1.0.0-RC1
...
org.apache.camel:camel-mybatis:2.7.0
org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.mybatis:3.0.2_1
```

Note that this assumes you're querying an existing *nexus* maven repo, and in addition this is just searching that *single* repo. (So it's not exactly what you asked.)

But, actually, this is the way I want it to be:  my *only* repository used by my maven projects is a single, internal (intranet) nexus server, and it functions as a mirror (and cache) of all the 3rd party repositories that I currently need. If I decide I need to pull in other jars from another repo (e.g., googlecode or company XYZ...), then I add that repo's url to my internal nexus configuration.  Everyone on my team -- netbeans/eclipse/mvn users -- always point to the single internal maven repo, & everyone automatically picks up the newly available artifacts.

Then you can still use the above script to search for an artifact. (Note: it lets you do a generic search, or a GAV (group/artifact/version) search.)

If you're not sure which repository a given artifact is in, I guess there's always http://mvnrepository.com/

Comment: Thanks for the effort to write an elaborate answer, I will take this as the answer `http://repository.sonatype.org/service/local/data_index?q=mybatis` and `http://search.maven.org/solrsearch/select?q=mybatis&rows=20&wt=json` very similar to your query but returns json instead. I liked the groovy idea too, for formatting the result. I have never used groovy, ruby or scala. I think its time to explore those as well.